# ZF2 Form getData returns unvalidated data

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-inputfilter

I just can't get my first ZF2 form to work!
Here is the abbreviated controller action to demonstrate my workflow:

```
$viewData['form'] = $form = new InstituteEditForm();
$form->setInputFilter(new InstituteInputFilter());
$defaultValues = ...;
$form->populateValues($defaultValues);
if ($request->isPost()) {
    $form->setData($request->getPost());
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        print_r('VALID<br/>');
        var_dump($form->getData());
    } else {
        print_r('INVALID<br/>');
        var_dump($form->getMessages());
        var_dump($form->getData());
    }
}
return new ViewModel($viewData);
```

The InstituteInputFilter defines Inputs with Filters and Validators for **some** elements, but not for all.
The problem is, that in case the form validates fine, form->getData() returns **all** values, not just those that have an Input attached, i.e. **it returns unvalidated data**. This should not be the case, should it?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I've found out, that there is a setting in ZF2.3.1 to attach `InputFilter`s by default, such that any form elements simply pass it, although I have NOT defined any validation.
Simply setting `$form->setUseInputFilterDefaults(false)` yields the behaviour I was expecting: only those form elements that I have attached an Input to, may pass validation. Thus, no unvalidated data is returned by `$form->getData`.

Answer (score 0):

the normal step to setup a form is the following below. i comment the code so you should have no problem to understand what method is used for. your main error is that you don't `bind` the default values to the form class.

```
$defaultValues = .....; // call db entity from db or whatever

$form = new \MyModule\Form\InstituteEditForm();
$form->setInputFilter(new InstituteInputFilter());

// bind the default values belong to this form
$form->bind($defaultValues);

if( $this->getRequest()->isPost() )
{
    // ok post now setup the post values to the form
    $form->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());

    if( $form->isValid() )
    {
        $validatedFormData = $form->getData();

        // update entity in db or whatever
        // $db->update($validatedFormData);
        // success messages, redirect...

    } else {

        // uuppps some fields contain errors
        $form->populateValues($this->getRequest()->getPost());

        // get all form errors
        $errorMessages = $form->getMessages();
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, $form->bind() internally calls populatesValues with those values extracted by the hydrator. Thus, directly calling populateValues() as I did above, should yield the same result, but without using a hydrator?

Comment: Let me rephrase my concern: If you don't call `setInputFilter` nor `bind` in your code, ins0, then any entered form data will be valid, even though no validation takes place!